# Why is repository local directive in composer not working?

Tags: composer-php, dependency-management, packagist

There is a project "OctoberCMS" that has a library called "rain" viz. a dependency. I cloned them to my desktop using:

```
git clone --branch develop git@github.com:octobercms/october.git
git clone --branch develop git@github.com: octobercms/library.git
```

(Actually cloned forked versions but anyway showing the original repo URLs above)
So the thing is that I want to make changes and a PR to the library project. So I opened the composer.json inside october folder and then added:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../library",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
],
```

And since the main OctoberCMS project already has `october/rain` viz the library project as a dependency declared in it's composer, I changed the code from `"october/rain": "1.1.*",` to `"october/rain": "@dev",`, hoping that it will symlink and load the local repo. But it didn't work.

I figured that the other dependencies of OctoberCMS i.e. [system](https://packagist.org/packages/october/system), [backend](https://packagist.org/packages/october/backend) and [cms](https://packagist.org/packages/october/cms) also require `"october/rain": "1.1.*" and perhaps that is why composer loads the packagist version over my local clone. So instead, I tried using the replace directive, since I read that it helps to tell dependencies to ignore whatever is in the block as it's satisfied,

```
"replace" : {
    "october/rain": "~1.1.0"
},
```

hoping that composer will think that this is satisfied by the main project's composer directive with @dev but that didn't work either. When I finally removed the 3 requires i.e.:

```
"october/system": "1.1.*",
"october/backend": "1.1.*",
"october/cms": "1.1.*",
```

Then the symlinking works and indeed my local repo is referenced, however the project fails since it's dependencies don't exist. So I'm confused on what I could do to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell composer to use the `develop` branch, but create an [inline alias](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias) to a version that satisfies the other dependencies:

```json
{
    "require": {
        ...
    
        "october/rain": "dev-develop as 1.1.x-dev",

        ...
    }
}
```

For further development, I suggest you update the [branch alias](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#branch-alias) in the `october/rain` repository:

```json
{
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-development": "1.1.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

This needs to change with each release / development phase.